# How to calculate the final amount on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeignator, I am calculating the final amount. If any user enters the total amount that will calculate it and display in the final amount field.

I am adding the input field dynamically as well. I tried some code but it's not working.

I need to calculate using AJAX.

What I am trying to achieve is, This is my first page.
[image]

Now if any user enters the total amount something like this then it will display in the final amount field.
[image]

If the user wants to add more field the should click on add button and add the price and it will calculate it and display in the field box, I added in the 50. 
[image]

same as on this.

[image]

Would you help me out in this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".row_set"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_row_click"); //Add button ID
  var baseUrl = "http://localhost/test/";

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment

      $(wrapper).append('<div class="row_set custom_fields"><input type="text" name="single_price[]" id="single_p_price' + x + '" placeholder="single price"> <input type="text" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price' + x + '" placeholder="total amount"><div class="btn_row remove_field"> <span> - </span> Remove  </div></div>');
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    //$(this).parent('custom_fields').remove();
    $(this).closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x--;
  })
  /*comment start here $(".medication_info").on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {
    var that = $(this); // CHANGE HERE
    var total_p_price = that.val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: baseUrl + "/Access_control/calculate_amt",
      data: {
        total_p_price: total_p_price
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        console.log(html);
        var single_price = $('#final_amt').val(html);
      }
    });
  });comment end here*/
  $('.medication_info').on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {
    var totalSum = 0;
    $('input[id^=total_p_price]').each(function() {
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      if ($.isNumeric(inputVal)) {
        totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
      }
    });
    $('#final_amt').val(totalSum);
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="medication_info">
    <div class="row_set">
      <input type="text" name="single_price[]" id="single_p_price" placeholder="single price">
      <input type="text" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price" placeholder="total amount">
    </div>
    <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>
    <input type="text" name="final_amt" id="final_amt" placeholder="Final total">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function calculate_amt()
  {
   $total_p_price=$this->input->post('total_p_price');
     foreach ($total_p_price as $key => $value) {
      $final_amt +=$value;
     }
     echo $final_amt;
  }
```

Comment: In the code above, does the line `console.log(html);` display anything?

Comment: @ChrisLear, I am getting the error <p>Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()</p> in console

Comment: OK so in your controller you're expecting an array, but posting a string (`total_p_price = that.val()`). Do you want to post an array, or would you rather sum the values in js and post the total?

Comment: @ChrisLear, Yes, It will be an array or won't it depends upon the user.  if the user needs a single product then total_price won't array. If need more then one product then should click on "Add" button then it will display the dynamic field. Kindly check my snippet you will get idea

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer, which might do what you want. The big problem you have is that you're never sending an array, so your controller code (which expects an array) has no chance of running.

Comment: @ChrisLear, I updated y question. Hope you understand this time.

Comment: I understand. Your controller code is returning an error (invalid argument), because your javascript code is not sending an array parameter. My latest code in my answer addresses this problem by serializing the appropriate values before making the ajax call. That's what you need.

Comment: @ChrisLear, I found the answer to calculate the amount you can check my snippet now. but that Is not an Ajax. I need an ajax to solve this issue.

Comment: I've already edited my answer below to give the correct ajax call. I added a new class in order to be able to serialize your input fields

Comment: Yes, I checked but it's not sending the data to controller

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".row_set"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_row_click"); //Add button ID
  var baseUrl = "http://localhost/test/";

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment

      $(wrapper).append('<div class="row_set custom_fields"><input type="text" name="single_price[]" id="single_p_price' + x + '" placeholder="single price"> <input type="text" name="total_p_price[]" class="total_p_price" id="total_p_price' + x + '" placeholder="total amount"><div class="btn_row remove_field"> <span> - </span> Remove  </div></div>');
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    //$(this).parent('custom_fields').remove();
    $(this).closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x--;
  })
  $(".medication_info").on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {
    // Sum all the values in the total_p_price fields
    var that = $(this);
  

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: baseUrl + "/Access_control/calculate_amt",
  data: {
    total_p_price: $(".medication_info .total_p_price").serialize()
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function(html) {
    console.log(html);
    var single_price = $('#final_amt').val(html);
  }
});
 
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="medication_info">
    <div class="row_set">
      <input type="text" name="single_price[]"  id="single_p_price" placeholder="single price">
      <input type="text" name="total_p_price[]" class="total_p_price" id="total_p_price" placeholder="total amount">
    </div>
    <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>
    <input type="text" name="final_amt" id="final_amt" placeholder="Final total">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: AJAX because I have to calculate the single price, qty, shipping etc. I tried your code but it's displaying only 0 in the final_amt field

Comment: your controller code doesn't seem to do anything except add up the sum of the values in the `total_p_price` field. Which is what my code does. Put numbers into the right-hand column, and you should get a sum >0. If you want to calculate the value*price+shipping, that could almost certainly be done in the client code. A big problem you have is being able to tell where your bugs are: in the controller or in the js. I can't debug the controller because I can't run it.

Comment: Yes,because That code i haven't added in the question.

Comment: Maybe you need to simplify your question to pinpoint the actual problem, then. And include the code that you're running. You say "I tried some code but it's not working" in the question, and now when we discover some code that isn't working you say "that code i haven't added in the question". I doubt anyone can help you much under these circumstances

Comment: I mean, I need to calculate the final amount using ajax. I haven't added much more code because that is not related to the final amount. I just need when the user enters an amount in the total_price that calculate it and display in the final amount field but I want to use the AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Both jQuery and using AJAX to involve a server seems overkill for this operation.

```js
//Find elements in HTML
var singleProductPriceInput = document.getElementById("single_p_price");
var totalProductAmountInput = document.getElementById("total_p_price");
var finalTotalInput = document.getElementById("final_amt");
var button = document.getElementById("submitter");
//Update function
function updatePrice() {
    var singleProductPrice = parseFloat(singleProductPriceInput.value);
    var totalProductAmount = parseFloat(totalProductAmountInput.value);
    var result = (singleProductPrice * totalProductAmount);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        finalTotalInput.value = result.toFixed(2);
    }
}
//Submit function
function submit() {
    alert("Do your server stuff\nAJAX here");
}
//Bind event listeners
singleProductPriceInput.addEventListener("change", updatePrice);
singleProductPriceInput.addEventListener("keyup", updatePrice);
singleProductPriceInput.addEventListener("mouseup", updatePrice);
totalProductAmountInput.addEventListener("change", updatePrice);
totalProductAmountInput.addEventListener("keyup", updatePrice);
totalProductAmountInput.addEventListener("mouseup", updatePrice);
button.addEventListener("click", submit);
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="medication_info">
    <div class="row_set">
      <input type="number" name="single_price[]" id="single_p_price" placeholder="single price">
      <input type="number" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price" placeholder="total amount">
    </div>
    <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>
    <input type="text" name="final_amt" id="final_amt" placeholder="Final total" readonly>
  </div>
  <input id="submitter" type="button" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Please check my snippet. It's hard to understand your code. fields are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

simple `Javascript KeyUp Event` calculation

```js
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var pr = $(this).data("price");
    var name = $(this).data("name");
    var qut = $(this).val();
    var total = pr * qut;
    $("#"+name).text(total);
});
$("#placeorder").click(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.t').each(function () {
        total += Number($(this).text());
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
});
```

```css
.t{
    border:0px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Bone Burger:</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-name="gold" data-price="28" size="1" /></td>
        <td> * 28r.s<td>
        <td>= <label id="gold" class="t" readonly ></label>r.s</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Smoke Burger:</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-name="sakti" data-price="29" size="1" /></td>
        <td> * 29r.s<td>
        <td>= <label id="sakti" class="t" readonly ></label>r.s</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Voodoo Burger:</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-name="taja" data-price="30" size="1" /></td>
        <td> * 30r.s<td>
        <td>= <label id="taja" class="t" readonly ></label>r.s</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td>Ayhuaska Sour:</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-name="gay" data-price="18" size="1" /></td>
        <td> * 18r.s<td>
        <td>= <label id="gay" class="t" readonly ></label>r.s</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Beyond the Pale:</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-name="chhash" data-price="10" size="1" /></td>
        <td> * 10r.s<td>
        <td>= <label id="chhash" class="t" readonly ></label>r.s</td>
    </tr>     
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="placeorder">Place order</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Total:<span id="total"></span></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```